# SQL : ER Model, Foreign keys

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, entity-relationship

I have a simple question, but I am still confused about it.

Whenever you design an ER model, how are you supposed to draw PK's and FK's ?

Let's say I have two tables, User and Country

```
User
ID | firstName | lastName | FKCountry
1  | John      | Stewart  | 1
2  | Paul      | Duschmol | 2
etc.

Country
ID | country     | code
1  | Germany     | GER
2  | Switzerland | CH
etc...
```

Well, should I add the column "FKCountry" in the ER model or not ? I mean, there will be the relation (Rhombus) between both entities, but should I explicitly add the "FKCountry" by the User entity ?

Hope my question is clear, Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should add `FKCountry` to the `User` table in your ER diagram.  If the column exists in your table, it should be represented in the entity.  There should be zero doubt that the relational marker connects `Country.ID` to `User.FKCountry`.  Just because it is obvious in this example does not mean that in other relationships, the linked columns might not be named completely differently and not obvious.

Answer (score 2):

The primary purpose of `Foreign Key` is to enforce referential integrity between the two tables.

If the relationship of `Country` to a `User` is  `One-to-Many` then it should be fine for adding column `FKCountry` on table `User`.

However, if the relationship is `Many-to-Many` in which `Country` can have many `User` as well as `User` belongs to multiple `Country`, then a 3-table design is much preferred. Wherein the 3rd table is the association table between the other two.